# How can I import JS and CSS files only once in my project?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm writing a HTML web and I'm using some `JS` and `CSS`files.
After importing them once in the `index.html` I want to use them again in other pages. Is there a way to use them without importing them again in every page?

I'm using `Jquery Mobile` framework wrapped in `Phonegap`.

I have some experience with `AngularJS`, where I used the main page as a template, and all the other pages as `directives`. Therefor I included `JS` and `CSS` files only once.

Comment: Since you're working on a phonegap app, your files will probably be cached. So including there somewhere else isn't likely to hurt much...

Comment: With jQM Ajax navigation enabled, libraries are cached and reused.

Comment: As others have said the files will be cached, but you still need to include the files in other pages ( include them again in every page), if you are not using ajax

Comment: Okay thanks. This leads me to another question, how should I choose  when to use AJAX calls? As I see it for now, to load a page I need to call it with the AJAX disabled.

Comment: If use are using jquery mobile, you need to understand concept of single page application. In SPA, index will be loaded once, and you need to import your js and css files in index.html. For the other pages(index2.html) you need to write only body part as jquery mobile's page div and call jqm's pagechange() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the other pages you mentioned into the index.html (may with ajax call) you can avoid import them again on another page.

If you show a complete other page (e.g. index2.html) you have to import them again. But the browser will cache these files and do not downlaod them again.

Comment: Your second paragraph isn't correct. With Ajax enabled, jQM fetches _page div_ only and neglects other HTML tags.